# Отображение текста

Tags: html

Подскажите, в какие теги вставлять текст, который я вывожу из БД, чтобы он отобразился красиво (как есть)? Вроде ерундовая проблема, а не получается, ни  ни  ни какие-либо другие не помогли мне - или вообще не учитывает формат или вставляет какой-то фон и рамку на фон...

Comment: Что значит `как есть`? Как вы пытались вывести текст из базы данных? В какие теги помещали? Дополните вопрос, пожалуйста)

Comment: Чтобы текст отобразился как он в БД лежит - со всеми отступами, абзацами и т.д.. У меня он тупо весь одним абзацем отображается на странице

Comment: CSS `white-space: pre-wrap`?